# Is Thunderbird still being updated? Mine hasn't updated and a new update issued last week

Tags: thunderbird

Mozilla released an update to Thunderbird last week (version 3.1.10). This update addressed security issues. So my understanding is that 10.04 Ubuntu should receive the update. But my Thunderbird installation from the Main repository has not updated. Why not?

Do I have the configuration wrong? To get updates do I need to install the Mozilla PPA?

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely get updates faster if you have the products own repository.

Thunderbird is here - https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-stable

Then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to using the PPA over the Main Repository (strictly speaking about the Mozilla Thunderbird PPA here)?

Answer (score 1):

This was pushed out on Thursday.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @StephenMyall This really is an answer, and not a comment. It addresses and resolves the question.